# Ping a URL with Laravel Forge scheduler (non Laravel app)

Tags: php, cron, laravel-forge

I am using Linode/Forge for a non-Laravel php project and I need to set up a cron job to ping a certain URL once a day. Can I do this using the Forge scheduler? And if so, how? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. You just use "wget http://mywebsite.com/myurl" and set the frequency.

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually need the "-q" parameter in order to allow the output to finish. So the full command for the Laravel Forge Scheduler would be:

```
wget -q https://example.com/command
```